# Is there any way to compare a list object and add specific items

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a `List` which contains the order details of several users such as `StoreId`, `OrderTotal`, `dateModified` etc. I want to add the order total which fall under same date but different time.

Below is the code which fetches data from the database. Also I have attached the output which I am getting.

An example of what I am trying to do is: if there are `2` orders for `08/09/2020` then I want to add the `orderValue`. The third column in the image refers to order value.

[image]

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGet()
{
    try
    {
        StoreOrderDetails = new List<Store_Order>();
        StoreOrderDetails2 = new List<Store_Order>();
        var res = await UOW.CurrentContext.StoreOrder
            .OrderBy(x => x.OrderModified)
            .ToListAsync();

        foreach (var item in res)
        {
            if(item.Status.ToString() == "PaymentComplete" && 
               item.StoreId == defaultStoreId)
            {
                StoreOrderDetails.Add(item);
            }
        }

        totalCount = StoreOrderDetails.Count();
        StoreId = defaultStoreId;

        StoreOrderDetails.GroupBy(x => x.OrderModified).Select(grpData =>
            new Store_Order
            {
                OrderModified = grpData.Key,
                OrderTotal = grpData.Sum(item => item.OrderTotal),
            });
    }
    catch
    {
    }

    return Page();
}
```

Comment: As you are a professing newbie please do not write empty catch blocks. They will give rise to misery and prevent you from learning. It's almost certainly better not to handle the exception at all

Comment: Thank you so much @ Aluan Haddad. I will remove the catch or add exception handler. But can you help me out in this situation. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that first column in your image is the date you refer to in code when you say `x => x.OrderModified`, you'll need to group by only the date element, excluding the time:

```
StoreOrderDetails.GroupBy(x => x.OrderModified.Date).Select(grpData =>
                                              ^^^^^
```

When you group a date that has a time too, then events will go into different groups if they are even only a nanosecond different. If you want dates to group according to the day all different things happened on, then you have to group by the date without the time. The easiest way to do this is to ask for a DateTime's Date property - it's the date, but with the time of midnight. If you fake it as if all orders occurred at midnight, then the Sum will work out

Oh, and you'll actually need to store/use the results of the group operation...

Comment: Thank you so much @Caius Hard for you reply and time. It's actually the third column in the image and yeah I want to use the results of the group operation. Could you please help me out?

Comment: I meant "if that first column is the data you're grouping by". The image is hard work because it doesn't have any headers. Do you know how a LINQ grouping works?

Comment: Appreciate your reply and efforts. Can you see the image properly or else i will upload a new one. The first column in the image is the date. I want to group data in the third column with same date value. I am little bit aware of how Linq works but not much so it would great if you help out

Comment: Your image doesn't have headers, so it makes life hard work. I did say this before. You said you want to group by date, and the code I posted groups by date but I can't guarantee that the data in the OrderModified property is that first column in the image - I'm just guessing. If it's not, you need to use a different date property (like x.OrderCreated.Date - whatever that first column of dates is)

Comment: Thank you everybody. I think I have figured it out. It would not have been possible without your guidance and support. Means a lot.